# if a buttons text is empty, then

Tags: android, if-statement

In this code I want to make a buttons visibility gone, if the text of the button is "":

```
        if (button TEXT IS "")
    {
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }    

    else 
    {

        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

How can I form the if-Statement to get a result?
Thank you!

Comment: if (button.getText() ==null)

Comment: Have you set button text at run time?

Comment: button text is set by User if he's edit a text in an EditText field. So I don't know if he is doing it but if not i want that the button is not visible.

Comment: You add a listener to your `EditText` and as soon as the user finishes writing (and he validates his edited input) you execute a method to check the Text (if empty or not) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if(button.getText() == null)
    {
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }    

    else 
    {

        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: "" means not null

Answer (score 1):

```
Button b = (Button)findViewByID("your button id");
String buttonText = b.getText().toString();

if (buttonText.equals("Your Text"))
    b.setVisibility(View.GONE);   

else 
    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

If you want to check if empty you may use

```
if(buttonText.isEmpty())
    b.setVisibility(View.GONE);   

else 
    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the question, try with the `Empty()` method to check if the length of the characters in your String is 0 or greater :

```
if(text.isEmpty()){

    //String is empty

}else{

    //String includes characters
}
```